# Business logic in Vue 3 + Pinia

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia

Let's say I have a simple webshop application using Vue 3. Whenever the user adds an item to the cart, I store it locally in Pinia and I send this event information to the backend as well.

By default what I would do is I would add a action to the Pinia store like `addItemToCart()` which would update the local `cartItems` reactive variable and would also send the request to the backend like `POST http://localhost/api/update-cart`.

My idea is to introduce a service layer into my application.
I would create a service like:

```js
const useCartService = () => {
  const cartStore = useCartStore()

  const updateCartApi = useUpdateCartApi()

  const addItemToCart = async (item) => {
    cartStore.loading = true

    await updateCartApi.mutate(item)

    cartStore.items.push(item)

    cartStore.loading = false
  }

  return {
    loading: cartStore.loading,
    
    addItemToCart,
  }
}
```

Would it make sense to separate the business logic from the Pinia store like this? Is it considered as a anti-pattern, or is this approach commonly used in Vue?

Comment: If you don't have an good reason to not keep this code in Pinia then no, it doesn't make sense. Global store is good for business logic, not just as a replacement for global variables

Comment: My main reason is that some part of the app will require Pinia, some are not, and I dont want to mix the form of business logics, I want it to be consistent and put everything into the `services` folder and the ones that also require global state I just connect Pinia to them.

Comment: But you've already hard-cored this service to use Pinia with useCartStore, any part of the app that uses it already uses Pinia. Unless you share business logic with non-Vue apps, this shouldn't be a concern. Basically stores are efficiently what you call services, with some pros that Pinia adds. Pinia store !== global state. There can be multiple Pinia stores and they can be local

Comment: But not all services will use own store. For example lets say I want to implement Google and Facebook login alongside of the basic email/password login. All of these 3 types of logins will use the Pinia store called `auth-store`. If I dont split up these into individual services, then my `auth-store.ts` will grow and grow because I have to keep there all the `auth-store` related business logic.

Comment: Totally depends on your case. You could implement a *strategy* (vanilla JS with no reactivity) that auth *service* will use, this design can be often seen. You can also compose multiple auth stores when needed. Any way, if you need reactive state + methods that change it, that's a store. A "service" that wraps a store to not put business logic into it doesn't look like a viable entity to me

Comment: I am thinking about this for a while. I think separating business logic into plain JS/TS files and then using those from the state manager can be a good way to go for a better code organization.

Comment: i would do it the other way around.
the stores will use the services.
put the bussiness logic into the services.
you can change the state management later if needed.

Comment: Having a service to handle the cart is imho a good thing. What I find strange is that you keep a list in both the client and the server in your situation. Those lists could in theory become out of sync. Why not send the cart in the end, when user wants to buy and pay? Or, when sending the item getting added to the backend, supply the frontend with a new list that the backend then sends back as a result